# Report Viewer alignment issue

Tags: rdlc, reportviewer

I am using `RDLC Report` in my `asp.net mvc applicaiton` and have designed the report in the following manner

[image]

But its rendering in the following way

[image]

As you can see there is a space between `CourseTitle` and `Duration`.How can we avoid that space??

Comment: The white space there is because of the table on the right - additional rows are pushing the content down. The solution is to re-think the design of the report.

Comment: Ok.Great.Thanks for your response mate.